# I'm having a problem showing and hiding a div in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried to create a **custom select menu** using html,css and javascript. I'm having a problem in making the button (arrow in my case) toggle the display style of the div that contains the options.

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="default_option_category_index">
              <li>
                <div class="option_allcategories">
                    <p>All Categories</p>
                    <button id="ArrowCategoryIndex" class="fa fa-chevron-up" onclick="showCategoriesIndex()"></button>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
 <ul id="OptionsCategoryIndex" class="select_option_category_index">
//options
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
#ArrowCategoryIndex{
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.custom_select_box_1_index .select_option_category_index{
  background-color: var(--white);
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function showCategoriesIndex() {
  var arrow = document.getElementById("ArrowCategoryIndex"); //set rotation to 0deg
  var option_menu = document.getElementById("OptionsCategoryIndex");
  if (option_menu.style.display === "none"){
    option_menu.style.display = "block";
    arrow.style.transform = "rotate(0deg)";
  }
  else if (option_menu.style.display = "block"){
    arrow.style.transform = "rotate(180deg)";
    option_menu.style.display = "none";
  }

}
```

The "else if" part of the JavaScript code doesn't work, when i click at the button for the first time the menu pops up, but when i try to click again at the button nothing happens.

Comment: Your else is is not a comparison its an assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your else if here is not a comparison. `=` is assigning 'block' to be the display style.

```
if (option_menu.style.display === "none"){
    option_menu.style.display = "block";
    arrow.style.transform = "rotate(0deg)";
  }
  else if (option_menu.style.display = "block"){
    arrow.style.transform = "rotate(180deg)";
    option_menu.style.display = "none";
  }
```

Change it to `===`

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

`option_menu.style.display = "block"` should be `option_menu.style.display === "block"`